# Large Title UINavigationBar not collapsing with UITableView scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a large title navigation bar for my view controller that is supposed to animate and collapse when the user scrolls down. However, the navigation bar stays large and never animates down.
Below is the intended outcome (not my view controller), however my navigation bar doesn't collapse.

[image: Intended Animation]

Here is my current view setup. From some research, I believe the issue is because the `UITableView` has to be the first subview for the animation to happen. I haven't found a solution for any way around this.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bottomPadding: CGFloat = 12.5
    
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    setupTableView()
    
    view.insertSubview(animationView, belowSubview: tableView)
    animationView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: bottomPadding, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
    animationView.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    animationView.layer.cornerRadius = bottomPadding*2
    animationView.clipsToBounds = true
    animationView.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: As you said tableview must be the first subview of view for the animation. When you insertSubview below to tableview this rule is broken.

Comment: @Alihan Yes, however I am seeing if there is any way around this.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do that, as I know. Because of that I added my segments, which are located under the navigation bar, inside of tableview.